# Как реализовать аутентификация между (spring) REST-Cервером и Android приложением

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, auth

Привет RU.SO, есть сервер который предостовляет `Rest.API` с `Basic auth`. 
Есть клиент-сайд приложение на Андроиде, в котором user-password захардкодены и передаються при requests. Проблема состоит в том что пользователь может дезасемблить приложения и получить все request-urls и данные для авторизации. Можно создать авторизацию через токен, но опять же пользователь сможет получить например этот токен через postman и потом скомпромитировать данные, суть вопроса, как всетаки реализовать security?

Comment: Через логин-пароль для каждого юзера, любый хардкоженные пароли это дыра.

Comment: @Vartlok так а я о чем и говорю, что это не вариант как оно сейчас работает. Есть API - который возврощяет все данные из табилицы Х, и надо релизовать так что бы это было возможно только через Android device. Тот факт что это будет делаться из под другово пользователя проблему не решает тк имея данные для авторизации (пусть они и будут для каждого пользователя уникальны ) можно будет использовать любой другой REST-Client где можно увидеть ответы с сервера, на Android device это же все работает в бэкенде

Comment: Вы уверены, что кому то настолько сильно нужны Ваши данные, чтобы так сильно заморачиваться и что Ваше решение будет дешевле потенциального убытка?

Comment: Правильно ли я Вас понимаю, что Вы не хотите отдавать Ваши данные клиенту никаким другим способом кроме как через Ваш клиент?

Comment: от дизассемблинга и подделки запросов Вас ничего не спасет. с учетом того что подделыывать запросы будут пользователи, которые и так имеют доступ к данным. Для всего остального есть OAUTH2